# I'm getting an error when I try to find the average

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, average, where-clause

```
SELECT AVG(product.product_price) 
  from product
     , customer
     , orderline
     , orders 
 WHERE product.product_id = orderline.product_id 
   AND orderline.order_id = orders.order_id 
   and = orders.cust_id = customer.cust_id 
   AND customer.city LIKE 'Tuscon'
 group 
    by product.name
```

I'm trying to find the average price of a product ordered by a customer in tucson

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: there is an extra = in line 5

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want:

```
select avg(p.product_price) 
from product p
inner join orderline ol on ol.product_id = p.product_id
inner join orders    o  on o.order_id = ol.order_id 
inner join customer  c  on c.cust_id = o.cust_id
where c.city = 'Tuscon'
```

This computes the average product price for all sales in Tucson - which is how I understand your question and your attempt.

Note that this uses standard joins (with the `on` keyword) rather than old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the from `from` clause); this legacy syntax should not be used in new code.

Note also that parentheses around conditions are usually not necessary, unless you are mixing `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a syntax issue in line 5. Also, no need of putting where clause in braces. Further, you try using JOIN instead of ','.

```
SELECT product.name, AVG(product.product_price) 
from product 
    inner join orderline on product.product_id = orderline.product_id
    inner join orders on orderline.order_id = orders.order_id 
    inner join  customer on orders.cust_id = customer.cust_id
WHERE  customer.city LIKE 'Tuscon'
group by product.name
```

Comment: I tried using that, however I'm getting a blank query

Comment: It's also highly unlikely that this is a case sensitive collation

Comment: it may be the case there is no matching condition as we are using inner join you can check if it is the join that is filtering the result. You can try using outer or right joins.